# JSFiddle Demo will not load

Tags: github, jsfiddle

I've read the docs, can someone tell me why this repo won't open in JSFiddle?

Here is the path to my repo on GitHub
https://github.com/mediawiz/examples/tree/master/examples/demo

I'm using the URL below:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/mediawiz/examples/tree/master/examples/demo

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_read.html), to integrate jsFiddle with a GitHub repository, use the URL:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/{framework}/{version}/{github_tree}/
```

In your example, you've forgotten the trailing slash after your `github_tree` path:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/mediawiz/examples/tree/master/examples/demo/